# props.history.listen causing page slowness

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-router

In my React app, I have the following code in one of my common function component. So basically, on each route change, I check if user has access to that page or not (so kind of global logic)

```
let history = useHistory();
props.history.listen((location, action) => {    
   checkIfUserHasAccessToPage();    
});
```

However, with this code, I observe slowness and lag on the UI on subsequent page navigation i.e. while user in the same session.

Is there any alternative I can use to avoid the perf issue ?

Answer (score 0):

If you are adding a history listener in the function component body then each time the component renders it adds another listener. This is an unintentional side-effect. You should add only one history listener and callback. Use a mounting `useEffect` hook for this, and don't forget to return the `unlisten` callback to be used in the `useEffect` hook's cleanup function.

Example:

```
const history = useHistory();

React.useEffect(() => {
  const unlisten = history.listen((location, action) => {    
    checkIfUserHasAccessToPage();    
  });

  return unlisten;
}, []);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. Other option I was considering is useEffect(() => {}, [location]);

where location = useLocation()

Comment: Do you think the above alternative can also be used for perf?

Comment: Also in case I go with your example, then for the cleanup, is just returning unlisten as you have shown sufficient ?

Comment: @copenndthagen Sure, I suppose that would work as well since it doesn't seem like you *actually* need the `location` object or navigation action (`PUSH`, `REPLACE`, `POP`, etc...).

Comment: @copenndthagen Yes, `unlisten` is a function, and any thing returned from the `useEffect` hook is interpreted/exptected to be a function that will be invoked before the next effect is applied or when the component is unmounting.

Comment: Yes..Actually in my logic inside, all I use is location.pathname ...So, I do get pathname even by using useEffect(() => {}, [location])

Comment: Based on my initial testing, both seems to be working fine...So think either of these should be fine in terms of performance

Comment: @copenndthagen `pathname` is a property on `location`, so I think it's pretty safe to assume you'll have it. In terms of performance, yeah, probably not a significantly measurable difference.

Comment: @copenndthagen Any further question(s)/concern(s)?